# Правильная сортировка

Tags: логика

Наткнулся на статью интересную про формирование "честного" рейтинга фильмов кинопоиска http://habrahabr.ru/post/172065/

И тут меня посетила мысль сделать вывод фильмов на своем сайте с формулой сортировки

(ср.знач. kinopoisk + ср.знач. imdb) / 2

Учитывая притом и голоса.

Есть мысли?

Comment: А какие могут быть мысли? Обыкновенная сортировка по внешнему ключу — ничего сверхъестественного или сложного.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

мысли: распарсить эти два сайта, так чтобы в итоге было две базы данных (если уже есть база данных - то хорошо)), потом генерировать запросом объединением таблицы по уникальному значению (не знаю насколько уникально, название фильма в связке с годом производства) - дополнительным столбцом рейтинг по твоей формуле,
и добавить сортировку по этому значению. 
В принципе ничего сложного. Добавить рейтинг: по жанрам, годам, режиссерам....

Comment: чтобы учитывать голоса:(ср.знач. kinopoisk/q1 + ср.знач. imdb/q2) / 2
где q1 q2 соответственно количество проголосовавших.